# 41DegreeSoftware.FFImagePicker in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimagepickercontroller

There is one package to support multiple image pick in NuGet.

It's `41DegreeSoftware.FFImagePicker`.

But I can't find any description that explains how to use it in Xamarin.iOS.

If anyone already used it in your app, please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the usage of `UIImagePickerController` , you can find a similar class called `FFImagePickerController` here.

Try this

```
FFImagePickerController controller = new FFImagePickerController();
controller.SingleSelect = false;
controller.MaxSideLength = 3;
controller.FinishedSuccessfully += (EventArgs e) =>
{
    controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
};
controller.GeneratedImages += (List<UIImage> images, EventArgs e) =>
{
    //get image list.
};
controller.Cancelled += (EventArgs e) =>
{
    controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
};
this.PresentViewController(controller, true, null);
```